# zend addElements form onchange select

Tags: forms, zend-framework, select, dynamic, onchange

I try to add dinamically a form input Elemnt on onchange of select element.
I have this code:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'nationality', array(
        'multiOptions' => array('CH' => 'Choose','IT' => 'Italy', 'other' => 'Other'),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Nation',
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'onChange' => '???'
    ));
```

I try to paste my new element instead "???"

```
$this->addElement('select', 'nationality', array(
        'multiOptions' => array('CH' => 'Choose','IT' => 'Italy', 'other' => 'Other'),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Nation',
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'onChange' => '$this->addElement(
                         'text', 'codice_fiscale', array(
                         'required' => true,
                         'label' => 'Codice fiscale',
                         'required' => true
        ))'
    ));
```

I know is not correct, but I dont' found any documentation about it.
How can I add an element onchange select value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem in a different way, if it's possible for you: 
javascript functions to call on the onChange. It would be syntax correct (and, as you said, what you wrote is not correct, it's going to be printed out entirely on the onChange attribute, not interpreted through php).

so, i would write

```
'onChange' => 'addElement()'
```

and then declare the javascript function which handles new elements. Or, you can prepare the elements before (if you have a fixed number), and show / hide them. It may be convenient if you don't have much elements, but if they're too many, just add through javascript the needed one.

PseudoCode Javascript

```
function addElement()
{
    // add your element here, or show / hide it
}
```

As far as I saw from my experience and similar cases

([Zend_form_element_select onchange in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645586/zend-form-element-select-onchange-in-zend-framework),

[Zend Form: onchange select load another view content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126894/zend-form-onchange-select-load-another-view-content))

you won't escape from Javascript if you want to handle the "onChange"

Comment: Yes I try, but my idea is declare other fields too in Zend platform and control this by onchange of select. Ideas with this method?

Comment: As far as I know, you will need javascript ( jQuery for example ) to handle an onChange event. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126894/zend-form-onchange-select-load-another-view-content) So, I would add all the elements you want, set them ad disabled / invisible, and use the javascript function just to show / enable the ones you want

Comment: Ok thanks a lot @Gounemond. Potevamo parlare in italiano credo ^__^